# How to parse "[ "a", [ "adidas", "acb", "amazon" ] ] to object java?

Tags: java, android

I can't converter this response api "[     "a",     [         "adidas",         "acb",         "amazon" ] ] to object java or kotlin

Comment: what have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I need a solution to convert this message to object java... I will try to use Gson but I can't write model to convert this

Comment: `[ "a", [ "adidas", "acb", "amazon" ] ] ` seems to be an array of `String, List<String>`.  The first `"` seems to be wrong

Comment: I write data class AutoComplete(@Expose val tmp:String, @Expose val list:List<String>
)
but can't convert :(

Comment: [Please add a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

The format of your JSON data is not very suitable to convert to a java object directly，try to make your JSON data like this:

`{"a": ["adidas", "acb", "amazon"] }`

or

`{"keyA" : "a", "keyB" : ["adidas", "acb", "amazon"] }`

But it's still depends on what is your actual demand

You can test your JSON data here:

[JSON to JAVA Converter live](https://codebeautify.org/json-to-java-converter)

Answer (score 0):

May be this example can help you.

public class Test {

```
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        String json = "[ "a", [ "adidas", "acb", "amazon" ] ];  
        // Now do the magic.
        Data data = new json().fromJson(json, Data.class);

        // Show it.
        System.out.println(data);
    }

}

class Data {
    private String data;
    private List<String> groups;

    public String getData() { return data; }
    public void setData(String data) { this.data= data; }
    public List<String> getGroups() { return groups; }
    public void setGroups(List<String> groups) { this.groups = groups; }
    }
```